# How to split text values by a delimiter?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, powerquery

I need to analyze a database. I want to merge all cells I need with each other with a delimiter `@`. Now, I want to separate the string value in another sheet by the `@` delimiter (see the screenshot). It needs to be done via a formula.

[image: Screenshot of the worksheet]

Comment: You tagged Excel, GS and PowerQuery. Please be specific about what app you want to use and do remove unwanted tags. Please also edit your post and include you own attempt.

Comment: Use find() to get the position of @, then left() mid() or right() to get the bits and join with &.

Comment: Also, if you just want to separate these values just use text to columns. Why a formula? If a formula, it also is handy to know your version of Excel. In either case, this has to be a duplicate as this is asked many times before.

Comment: Please provide proper hash tags, as mentioned by @JvdV Sir, unless you provide proper hash tags it becomes difficult for a person to provide solutions, accordingly, `GS` and `Excel` though looks same but functionality differs, also you need to provide what you have tried.!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the [Split function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) should do what you want. e.g.:

```
=Split(A1, "@")
```

[Example of Split used to split text by delimiter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osoPH.png)